# ThreadSafeKeyedObservableCollection<TKey, TItem>

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is this a thread safe collection? Any issues with the code?

```
public class ThreadSafeKeyedObservableCollection<TKey, TItem> : IObservableList, IList<TItem>
    where TItem : IKeyProvider<TKey>
{
    #region Fields

    private Dictionary<TKey, TItem> _dict;

    private IList<TItem> _collection;
    private readonly object _locker = new object();


    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public ThreadSafeKeyedObservableCollection(List<TItem> members)
    {
        InitializeFromList(members);
    }

    // added to avoid calling  nethod in constructor
    private void InitializeFromList(List<TItem> members)
    {
        _dict = new Dictionary<TKey, TItem>();

        // leaving as for for speed
        foreach (var item in members)
        {
            _dict.Add(GetKeyFromItem(item), item);  //Throws ArgumentException if duplicates
        }
        _collection = members;

    }
    public ThreadSafeKeyedObservableCollection()
    {
        _dict = new Dictionary<TKey, TItem>();
        _collection = new List<TItem>();
    }

    public ThreadSafeKeyedObservableCollection(int size)
    {
        _dict = new Dictionary<TKey, TItem>(size);
        _collection = new List<TItem>(size);
    }

    #endregion

    private bool _eventsEnabled = true;
    public bool EventsEnabled
    {
        get { return _eventsEnabled; }
        set { _eventsEnabled = value; }
    }



    public void Add(TItem item)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            _dict.Add(GetKeyFromItem(item), item);
            _collection.Add(item);
        }
        OnCollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item));

    }

    public bool AddIfNotPresent(TItem item)
    {
        bool added = false;
        lock (_locker)
        {
            var key = item.GetKey();
            if (!_dict.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                _dict.Add(GetKeyFromItem(item), item);
                _collection.Add(item);
                added = true;
            }
        }
        OnCollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item));
        return added;
    }

    public bool AddOrUpdate(TItem item)
    {
        var added = false;
        var updated = false;
        var oldItem = default(TItem);

        lock (_locker)
        {
            var key = item.GetKey();
            if (!_dict.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                _dict.Add(key, item);
                _collection.Add(item);
                added = true;
            }
            else
            {
                oldItem = _dict[key];
                var index = _collection.IndexOf(oldItem);

                if (index >= 0)
                {
                    _collection[index] = item;
                    _dict[key] = item;

                    updated = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (updated)
            OnCollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, item, oldItem));
        else if (added)
            OnCollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item));

        return updated || added;
    }

    public void AddOrUpdateRange(IList<TItem> items)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            foreach (TItem item in items)
            {
                var key = item.GetKey();
                if (!_dict.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    _dict.Add(key, item);
                    _collection.Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    var oldItem = _dict[key];
                    var index = _collection.IndexOf(oldItem);

                    if (index >= 0)
                    {
                        _collection[index] = item;
                        _dict[key] = item;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        OnCollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add,
            (IList)items));
    }

    public void AddRange(IList<TItem> items)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            foreach (TItem item in items)
            {
                _dict.Add(GetKeyFromItem(item), item);
                _collection.Add(item);
            }
        }

        OnCollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add,
            (IList)items));

    }

    public void AddRange(IList items)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            foreach (Object o in items)
            {
                VerifyValueType(o);
                var item = (TItem)o;
                _dict.Add(GetKeyFromItem(item), item);
                _collection.Add(item);
            }
        }

        OnCollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add,
            items));

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs a clear via a "NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace", which provides an opportunity to 
    /// get to the old items, for celanup purposes.  If you are unable to use range operations in your
    /// code, then use the Reset operation
    /// </summary>
    public void Clear()
    {
        BatchReplace(new List<TItem>());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs a tradition clear, via "NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset"
    /// </summary>
    public void Reset()
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            _collection.Clear();
        }
        OnCollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public bool Contains(TItem item)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            return _dict.ContainsKey(GetKeyFromItem(item));
        }

    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            return _dict.ContainsKey(key);
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsAnyKey(IEnumerable<TKey> items)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            return items.Any(_dict.ContainsKey);
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsAllKeys(IEnumerable<TKey> items)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            return items.All(_dict.ContainsKey);
        }
    }

    public void CopyTo(TItem[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            _collection.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }
    }
    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                return _collection.Count;
            }
        }
    }
    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool RemoveByKey(TKey key)
    {
        if (_dict.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return Remove(_dict[key]);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool Remove(TItem item)
    {
        bool result;
        int index = -1;
        lock (_locker)
        {
            result = _dict.Remove(GetKeyFromItem(item));

            if (result)
            {
                index = _collection.IndexOf(item);
                if (index >= 0)
                    _collection.RemoveAt(index);
            }

        }
        if (result)
            OnCollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item, index));
        return result;
    }


    public bool RemoveRangeByKey(IList<TKey> keys)
    {
        IList<TItem> items = new List<TItem>();
        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            if (_dict.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                items.Add(_dict[key]);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return RemoveRange(items);
    }

    public bool RemoveRange(IList<TItem> items)
    {
        bool result = false;
        lock (_locker)
        {
            foreach (TItem item in items)
            {
                result = _dict.Remove(GetKeyFromItem(item));

                if (result)
                {
                    int index = _collection.IndexOf(item);
                    if (index >= 0)
                        _collection.RemoveAt(index);
                }
            }
        }
        if (result)
            OnCollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, (IList)items));
        return result;
    }

    public bool RemoveRange(IList items)
    {
        bool result = false;
        lock (_locker)
        {
            foreach (Object o in items)
            {
                VerifyValueType(o);
                var item = (TItem)o;
                result = _dict.Remove(GetKeyFromItem(item));

                if (result)
                {
                    _collection.Remove(item);
                }
            }
        }
        if (result)
            OnCollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, items));
        return result;
    }

    //Enumerator should be should be returned under lock
    public IEnumerator<TItem> GetEnumerator()
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            var copy = new List<TItem>(_collection);
            return copy.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    //Delegate the explicit implementation to the implicit one above
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public int IndexOf(TItem item)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            return _collection.IndexOf(item);
        }
    }
    public void Insert(int index, TItem item)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= _collection.Count)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index", "Invalid Index");
            }
            _dict.Add(GetKeyFromItem(item), item);
            _collection.Insert(index, item);

        }

        OnCollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, index));

    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        TItem result;
        lock (_locker)
        {
            if (_collection.Count == 0 || _collection.Count <= index)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index", "InvalidIndex");
            result = _collection[index];
            _collection.RemoveAt(index);
            _dict.Remove(GetKeyFromItem(result));
        }

        OnCollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, result, index));

    }
    public TItem this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                TItem result;
                _dict.TryGetValue(key, out result);
                return result;
            }
        }

    }
    public TItem this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                return _collection[index];
            }

        }
        set
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                if (index < 0 || index >= _collection.Count)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                }
                _collection[index] = value;
                _dict.Add(GetKeyFromItem(value), value);
            }

            OnCollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, value, index));

        }
    }
    public void BatchReplace(List<TItem> newItems)
    {
        List<TItem> oldItems;
        lock (_locker)
        {
            // If both lists are 0, a range exception is thrown
            if (newItems.Count == 0 && _collection.Count == 0) return;

            oldItems = _collection.ToList();

            _collection.Clear();
            _dict.Clear();

            foreach (TItem data in newItems)
            {
                _collection.Add(data);
                _dict.Add(GetKeyFromItem(data), data);
            }
        }

        OnCollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace,
            newItems, oldItems));
    }

    public void BatchRemove(List<TItem> oldItems)
    {
        var newItems = new List<TItem>();
        lock (_locker)
        {
            foreach (TItem data in oldItems)
            {
                _collection.Remove(data);
                _dict.Remove(GetKeyFromItem(data));
            }
        }

        OnCollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace,
            newItems, oldItems));

    }

    public void UpdateCollection(List<TItem> changedItems)
    {
        var newItems = new List<TItem>();
        lock (_locker)
        {
            foreach (var ci in changedItems)
            {
                var key = ci.GetKey();
                var index = _collection.IndexOf(_dict[key]);

                _dict[key] = ci;
                if (index > -1)
                    _collection[index] = ci;
                else
                    _collection.Add(ci);
            }
        }

        OnCollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, newItems, changedItems));
    }

    public void OnCollectionChanged(Object source, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (EventsEnabled && CollectionChanged != null)
            CollectionChanged(source, e);

    }

    protected TKey GetKeyFromItem(TItem i)
    {
        TKey key = i.GetKey();
        return key;
    }


    #region IList Members

    int IList.Add(object value)
    {
        VerifyValueType(value);
        lock (_locker)
        {
            Add((TItem)value);
            return Count - 1;
        }

    }

    void IList.Clear()
    {
        Clear();
    }

    bool IList.Contains(object value)
    {
        if (IsCompatibleObject(value))
        {
            return Contains((TItem)value);
        }
        return false;
    }

    int IList.IndexOf(object value)
    {
        if (IsCompatibleObject(value))
        {
            return IndexOf((TItem)value);
        }
        return -1;
    }

    void IList.Insert(int index, object value)
    {
        VerifyValueType(value);
        Insert(index, (TItem)value);
    }

    bool IList.IsFixedSize
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    bool IList.IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    void IList.Remove(object value)
    {
        if (IsCompatibleObject(value))
        {
            Remove((TItem)value);
        }
    }

    void IList.RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        RemoveAt(index);
    }

    object IList.this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return this[index];
        }
        set
        {
            VerifyValueType(value);
            this[index] = (TItem)value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICollection Members

    void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        var arg = array as TItem[];
        if (arg != null)
            CopyTo(arg, index);
    }

    int ICollection.Count
    {
        get { return Count; }
    }

    bool ICollection.IsSynchronized
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    object ICollection.SyncRoot
    {
        get { return _locker; }
    }

    private static bool IsCompatibleObject(object value)
    {
        if ((value is TItem) || (value == null && !typeof(TItem).IsValueType))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static void VerifyValueType(object value)
    {
        if (!IsCompatibleObject(value))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid type");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public IEnumerable<TKey> Keys()
    {
        return _dict.Keys.ToList();
    }

    public TItem TryFindByKey(TKey key, out bool result)
    {
        if (_dict.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            result = true;
            return _dict[key];
        }
        result = false;
        return default(TItem);
    }
}

public interface IObservableList : INotifyCollectionChanged, IList
{
}

public interface IKeyProvider<out TK>
{
    TK GetKey();
}
```

Comment: I didn't read the whole code so my suggestion might be off-topic, but do you know the existence of `ConcurentBag<T>` and the `ConcurentDictionary<T>`?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with regards to being thread-safe:

1:

```
public IEnumerable<TKey> Keys()
{
    return _dict.Keys.ToList();
}

public TItem TryFindByKey(TKey key, out bool result)
{
    if (_dict.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        result = true;
        return _dict[key];
    }
    result = false;
    return default(TItem);
}
```

Each of these should have `lock`s around the dictionary access.

2:

```
public void OnCollectionChanged(Object source, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (EventsEnabled && CollectionChanged != null)
        CollectionChanged(source, e);

}
```

If the subscriber unsubscribes between the `if` and the `condition, you could get an exception. Idiomatic way of writing this is:

```
public void OnCollectionChanged(object source, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.EventsEnabled)
    {
        return;
    }

    var collectionChanged = this.CollectionChanged;

    if (collectionChanged != null)
    {
        collectionChanged(source, e);
    }
}
```

Other code issues:

- spacing before and after curly braces is inconsistent.
- use of `#region`s is frowned upon these days.
- move code from `InitializeFromList()` into the constructor which calls it and mark `_dict` and `_collection` as `readonly`.
- Any method with `Or` in it (i.e. `AddOrUpdate()`) would be best as either renamed to `Upsert` (SQL terminology) or split out into two separate methods. I'd go with the latter. It also removes the `AddIfNotPresent()`.

Comment: You failed to mention *why* regions are frowned upon. They're generally an indication that the class is doing too much. I feel like they've been judiciously used here to group the different *kinds* of code within the class.

Comment: Thank you, Jesse. You are right, I can't believe I missed those locks. Normally I use:

Comment: var collectionChanged = Volatile.Read(ref CollectionChanged); if (collectionChanged != null) { collectionChanged(source, e); }  for raising events.  Your version of raising event is fine too.